# Create WAR using ANT compatible with JBOSS

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jboss

i want to know if its possible to generate a war using Ant.

Nowadays we are using Eclipse to create the War( File -> Export -> War),but  I did an Ant script that create a War but it's not compatible with Jboss.

```
<zip destfile="${docflow4-web-home}/deploy/${nome}.war">
    <zipfileset dir="${docflow4-web-home}/web" />
</zip>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "zip" with "war" and supply a web.xml for your war:

```
<war destfile="${docflow4-web-home}/deploy/${nome}.war" webxml="path/to/web.xml">
  <zipfileset dir="${docflow4-web-home}/web"/>
</war>
```

For more details, check out the documentation at http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the war tag instead of zip. (You can also create the WAR structure then just use the jar tag to create a WAR file.)

Comment: Can you tell me how to enable this tag? it's my first time using Ant and i can't use <war> or <jar>